# How to replace or redirect in blogger

Tags: blogger

How to replace or redirect from ?m=1 to ?m=0 in blogger website..
My existing url is:-
https://www.sarkarinaukri.cloud/?m=1
I want to replace above URL to this url:-
https://www.sarkarinaukri.cloud/?m=0

How to replace or redirect from ?m=1 to ?m=0 in blogger website..

My existing url is:-

https://www.sarkarinaukri.cloud/?m=1

I want to replace above URL to this url:-

https://www.sarkarinaukri.cloud/?m=0

Comment: Add location redirect header in the first route, if its PHP refer this : https://www.bluehost.com/help/article/php-redirect